# Regex to Validate of exponential value Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am try to validate exponential value with the Regex below

```
var regularExp = /(([1-9]+\.[0-9]*)|([1-9]*\.[0-9]+)|([1-9]+))([eE])([-+]?[0-9]+)?/;
```

it is working fine. but some character string value like `"POTASSIUM CYANIDE GRAN 18-50KG DRM 9EB1"`, it is treating them also as an exponential value.

Can I have any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected result for the string you provided?

Comment: @Bikash: Do you want to match 18, 50 from above input?

Comment: If you want to validate a whole string is a number, you might want to use a classical `/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/`.